# vscode cpp build tasks.json type:"cppbuild" error

Tags: visual-studio-code

VSCode : 1.61.0
Linux: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

I'm trying to build c++ program using by VSCode.
when the run build, VSCode showing this message.

I know build tasking need matching launch.json file's preLaunchTask with tasks.json file's label. and I'm already set it.

tasks.json

```json
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild", // but "shell" is working
            "label": "C/C++: g++ build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

launch.json

```json
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "g++ - Build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++ build active file",
            "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb"
        }
    ]
}
```

The problem is, if I change the "type" value in tasks.json, from shell to cppbuild, It doesn't work and show the error message like to.

[showing error message when the run build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3Flq.png)

what is different "cppbuild" and "shell"? and What should I do how using "cppbuild" value?

Answer (score -1):

Te values of *cppbuild* are fine. Try changing in launch.json the value:

```
"preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++ build active file",
```

to:

```
"preLaunchTask": "cppbuild",
```

The difference between *shell* and *cppbuild* is that the first open the BASH and runs a command you write, the second, *cppbuild*, runs an specific binary (or program).